# How to get a small width size for image while implementing owl carousel

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I am currently implementing an image slider using owl carousel.

I realize that using this owl carousel, the images width will be automatically resized.

However I can't seem to be able to change the width of the images since it is really huge, even inline css wont help.

I believe I will need to fiddle into the javascript but this was how I  implemented `

```
        var $sync1 = $(".big-images"),
            $sync2 = $(".thumbs"),
            flag = false,
            duration = 300;

        $sync1
            .owlCarousel({
                items : 1,
                margin: 10,
                nav: false,
                dots: false

            })
            .on('changed.owl.carousel', function (e) {
                if (!flag) {
                    flag = true;
                    $sync2.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [e.item.index, duration, true]);
                    flag = false;
                }
            });

        $sync2
            .owlCarousel({
                margin: 20,
                items: 6,
                nav: true,
                center: true,
                dots: true
            })
            .on('click', '.owl-item', function () {
                $sync1.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(this).index(), duration, true]);

            })
            .on('changed.owl.carousel', function (e) {
                if (!flag) {
                    flag = true;        
                    $sync1.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [e.item.index, duration, true]);
                    flag = false;
                }
            });
    });
</script>`
```

Screenshot show how the images which was supposed to be only 250x260 was rendered.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXndu.jpg)

You can refer to this link as well: [Blink Homepage](http://www.kelvyap.com/blinkapp/test.html)

All the feedback or advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you style an image with CSS?

Comment: If you provide a [mcve] (using `<>` button and making sure it works) I'll help you style it up. You don't need `JavaScript` to make owl images fit.